# Add marker for system boot event to syslog

Tags: debian, rsyslog

I often reboot a development box and then have to sift through syslog.

How can I add a marker beetween the last line before shutdown and the first line of the new boot?

Box is Debian stable with rsyslog 8.4.2-1+deb8u2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the only point is to find the start of a new boot, you can just look for this regular expression in the logging output

```
 kernel: \[ *0.000000] Linux version
```

Answer (score 1):

The `logger` program is a command line interface to the logging system, so just run something like

```
logger -p kernel.notice "---------- Rebooting ---------"
```

before you reboot. There are lots more options.

Comment: Where would I add this? I don't want to enter this manually each time I reboot...

Comment: Depends on how you reboot! If you are entering a reboot command then just create a 2 line script that does the logger and calls the original program. If you are using something like ctrl-alt-del to do it then perhaps http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/security-ctrlaltdel.html will help you?

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is correct, but isn't there a central place where I can  configure this?

Comment: In general no. Part of the problem is deciding exactly where you need to put this call. You probably still want networking enabled in case you have rsyslog configured to do remote logging. If you only wanted to find out when the machine rebooted you could look for something like `kernel: \[ *0\.000000] Linux version`

Comment: OMG, not possible didn't think of that - that's the answer... please add it so I can accept it.